# How to associate names with IPs in a local network on a Ubuntu machine?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, localhost, hostname

I would like to be able to address the machines on a local network via hostnames.

I wonder if there is a file similar to hosts.txt on windows that I can edit on my Ubuntu machine to be able to associate the IPs in my network with host names.

Comment: Even better, Ubuntu comes with a preinstalled Avahi daemon that automatically discovers other devices in your local network and gives them network hostnames composed of the remote device's reported hostname and the `.local` domain suffix. That means, if you have two computers with hostnames `officepc` and `gamingpc`, you can address them with the URLs `officepc.local` and `gamingpc.local` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the /etc/hosts file.  This
       file is a simple text file that associates IP addresses with hostnames,
       one line per IP address.
[source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/hosts.5.html)